# WaitForNavigation alternative to ensure that no navigation is currently happening

Tags: puppeteer

A similar question may have been asked, but despite spending a couple of hours I could not find a satisfying answer.

I would like to call Frame.click().  At the time of calling it - I want to make sure that no navigation is pending.  I also don't know if the element I am about to click on will result in navigation (it's passed in dynamically).

I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/pending-xhr-puppeteer, but that seems to no longer be supported. (still uses Request instead of HTTPRequest)

Right now I am resorting to page.WaitForNetworkIdle().  Is this the best I can do?

P.S. It seems page.WaitForNavigation used to return right away if no navigation was taking place (on a year old version of the code).  Since I updated to 12.1 it started waiting for the timeout and then throwing an exception if no navigation started within that timeframe.

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing navigation and requests/responses. Navigation can be finished but requests/responses can still happened (eg: `.aspx` requests).

To make sure the navigation has happened, you could wrap it in a [promise via Promise.all() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
await Promise.all([
    page.click(`#submit`),
    page.waitForNavigation(),
]);
```

Additionally you could [`await page.content();`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagecontent) to make sure the full HTML contents of the page, including the doctype.

In the case of an ajax request you can use [`page.waitForResponse()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options):

```
await Promise.all([
    page.click(`#submit`),
    page.waitForResponse(response => response.status() === 200),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, @amarinediary.  The issue I have is that I don't know if navigation will happen after a click or keypress.  So what I am trying to do instead is make sure the _if_ navigation happened during the previous action, I can wait for it to complete before initiating the following action.  Using the Promise.all() as described assumes that a navigation will happen after the click.  What I want to do is wait for previously initiated navigation to complete before making the next click.  I hope this makes sense.